# Finding records where a field value not in a list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Using Any to filter an entity list that does not contain members of a list of values causes N seperate queries, one for each of the list members.

eg.

```
List<ImportObject> retval = new List<ImportObject>();
r = (from a in olist 
     where !ctx.Boxes.Any(o => o.OrderNo == a.OrderNo) 
     select a).ToList();
```

Using query profiler, I see bunches of statements come across like this.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Box] AS [o]
        WHERE [o].[OrderNo] = @__a_OrderNo_0)
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END',N'@__a_OrderNo_0 nvarchar(50)',@__a_OrderNo_0=N'13NU004094'
```

Is there a better way to do this type of action?

Comment: how big is the boxes table? where is olist calculated? could you add the relvant models to your question?

Comment: Box table has just over 1mil records and the table has 20 or so fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a left-outer join on the boxes table:

```
var elemeWithouthBoxMatch =
  (from elem in olist 
   join box in ctx.Boxes on box.OrderNo equals elem.OrderNo into matches
   from sbox in matches.DefaultIfEmpty()
   where sbox == null
   select elem).ToList();
```